# Mule check inbound http request is GET

Tags: mule, mule-el

I have an HTTP inbound endpoint which receives both GET and POST request. I notice one of the INBOUND scope properties is:

```
http.method=GET
```

Right after the http inbound endpoint, I have a choice, and I'd like to check if the message sent is GET or POST. One of my when expressions is:

```
#[message.getInboundProperties('http.method') == 'GET']
```

However, this does not work as it doesn't find message. Is there a way I can access the inbound property from my  element? I must be trying to get a hold of the value the wrong way.

Answer (score 4):

Easy answer, I took this from my groovy/Java elements, but it turns out I can just do:

```
#[message.inboundProperties['http.method'] == 'GET']
```

works like a charm.